# How to decorate class method

Tags: python, class, decorator

OK, I allready have read all questions about class method decorating, but my case not like them.

```
def safe_db(foo):
    def _inner(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            foo(args, kwargs)
            return True
        except Exception as e:
            log.error(e.message)
            print e.message
            return False
    return _inner


class BaseDB(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = Connection()
        self.db = self.connection.goobi
        self.table = None

    @safe_db
    def create(self, **data):
        self.table.insert(data)

    def update(self, where, **data):
        try:
            self.table.update(where, {'$set': data})
            return True
        except Exception as e:
           log.error(e.message)
           print e.message
           return False
```

And then I try call method create from inherited class User:

```
u = User()
u.create(email='i@example.com', password='secrete')
```

I get exception:

```
2012-09-08 18:17:18,230 ERROR [hairs.model.user][worker 2] create() takes exactly 1      argument (2 given)
    create() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

I cant understand how I can decorate class methods of BaseDB, or how I can make exceptions catch and logging less painfull ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your decorator:

```
def safe_db(foo):
    def _inner(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            foo(*args, **kwargs)   # fixed line
            return True
        except Exception as e:
            log.error(e.message)
            print e.message
            return False
    return _inner
```

Comment: many thx, my inattention makes me wrong

Answer (score -1):

You expect to call your function as `create(email='i@example.com', password='secret')`. You are calling the wrapper function as `u._inner(email='i@example.com', password='secret')`, which gets automatically translated (because you are calling a method) to `_inner(u, email='i@example.com', password='secret')`.

You should add `self` to `_inner`'s parameters, e.g. `_inner(self, ...`

However given your error and the numbers appearing in it, it may be the case that your error is not occurring in any code you are showing us; it may be happening in some subcall (which you can check by adding print statements when you enter/exit functions).

Comment: this doesnt works and i get same exception 2012-09-08 18:38:38,040 ERROR [hairs.model.user][worker 1] create() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
create() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)